# CSS backgroun image removal componet

Tags: html, css

this is concerning the website www.gaelglobal.org

please I need some help with editing the theme/CSS

specifically, I am trying to remove this background picture from the theme http://satimed.com/files/resized/89767/500;500;6615ca2cc8c1c75f3a609aa30fbc514f5bb87114.png

I tried to inspect the element to find where is located in the editing section of CSS (assets/css/style.css) but I can't find it.

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Signika|Rochester|Monda);

body {font: normal 14px 'Monda'; color: #666; background: #fff; margin: 0; padding: 0; line-height: 1.5;}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {color: #333;}
h1, h2, h3 {font: bold 25px 'Signika'; margin: 10px 0 10px 0;}
h1 a, h2 a, h3 a, h4 a, h5 a, h6 a {color: #00adef;text-decoration: none;}
h1 a:visited, h2 a:visited, h3 a:visited, h4 a:visited, h5 a:visited, h6 a:visited {color: #00adef;text-decoration: none;}
h1 a:hover, h2 a:hover, h3 a:hover, h4 a:hover, h5 a:hover, h6 a:hover {color: #1B5455;text-decoration: none;}

a, a:visited {color: #00adef;text-decoration: underline;}
a:hover {color: #1B5455;text-decoration: none;}
a img {border: none;}
ul, ol {padding-left: 25px;}

#header_wrapper {padding: 20px 0 40px 0; background: url(/assets/images/wavegrid.png) top left repeat;}

#header_background {background: #17ace4;box-shadow: inset 1px 4px 9px -6px #0E2D2E, inset 1px -4px 9px -6px #0E2D2E; }
#header_text {zoom: 1; overflow: hidden; padding: 40px 0; text-align: center;}
#header_text h1#site_heading {font: normal 90px 'Rochester';color: #fff; margin-bottom: 0px;}
#header_text h1#site_heading a {color: #fff;}
#header_text h2#site_subheading {font: normal 30px 'Signika';color: #eee; margin-top: 0px;}

#primary_navigation {font: normal 20px 'Monda'; width: 100%; zoom: 1; overflow: hidden;}
#primary_navigation ul {list-style-type: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; text-align: center; }
#primary_navigation ul li {display: inline-block; margin-right: 10px;}
#primary_navigation ul li a {display: inline-block; text-decoration: none; color: #333; padding: 15px 10px;}
#primary_navigation ul li a:hover, #primary_navigation ul li.active a {color: #00adef;}
#primary_navigation ul li.last {margin-right: 0px;}


#top_wrapper {padding-bottom: 10px;}
.location {padding: 10px;}
#right .location {background: #E0E0E0; margin-left: 17px;-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2);-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2);box-shadow:2px 2px 3px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2);}
#right {background: url(/assets/images/shadow.png) top left no-repeat; position: relative;top: -20px; left: 0px;}
.splash #right .location {background: #eee; margin-left: 0px;-webkit-box-shadow: none;-moz-box-shadow: none;box-shadow:none;}
.splash #right {background: none; position: relative;top: -0px; left: 0px;}

.navigation_component ul {list-style-type: none; font-size: 15px; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
.navigation_component ul a {text-decoration: none;}
.navigation_component ul li {padding: 5px 0; margin: 0;}
.navigation_component ul ul {padding-left: 25px; list-style-type:circle;}

.blog_component ul li a, .blog_archive_component ul li a {text-decoration: none;}
.blog_component ul, .blog_archive_component ul {list-style-type: none; padding-left: 0;}
.blog_component .blog_post ul {list-style-type: disc; padding-left: 30px;}

.metadata {font-size: 11px; border-top: 2px solid #ccc;}

.comment.owner {border: none; background: #eee;}
.comment {border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;}

.component input {min-height: 20px}
.component input, .component textarea {border: none; background: #fff; border: 1px solid #ccc; color: #666;}
input.form_field_submit_button, .submit_wrapper input {padding: 5px 10px; background: #00adef; color: #fff;}
input.form_field_submit_button:hover, .submit_wrapper input:hover {background: #1B5455; color: #fff;}

#footer_wrapper {background: #00adef; padding: 20px 10px; text-align: center; box-shadow: inset 1px 4px 9px -6px #0E2D2E; color: #fff;}
#footer_wrapper a, #footer_wrapper a:visited, #footer_wrapper a:hover {color: #fff;}
#footer_wrapper #powered_by {padding: 10px 0 20px 0;}






@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
  #header_background {margin-top: 15px;}
  #header_text {padding: 15px 0;}
  #header_text h1#site_heading {font-size: 40px;}
  #header_text h2#site_subheading {font-size: 30px;}
  #header_text h1#site_heading, #header_text h2#site_subheading {margin: 0px;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #right .location {background: #eee; margin-left: 0px;-webkit-box-shadow: none;-moz-box-shadow: none;box-shadow:none;}
  #right {background: none; position: relative;top: -0px; left: 0px;}
  #header_wrapper {padding-bottom: 10px;}
  #primary_navigation {font-size: 15px;}
  #primary_navigation ul li { margin-right: 5px;}
  #primary_navigation ul li a {padding: 5px;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  #primary_navigation {font-size: 18px;}
  h1, h2, h3 {font-size: 20px;}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 90 of your index.html file.  Comment it out, instead of deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

The only lines with reference to background images are:

`#header_wrapper {padding: 20px 0 40px 0; background: url(/assets/images/wavegrid.png) top left repeat;}`

and:

`#right {background: url(/assets/images/shadow.png) top left no-repeat; position: relative;top: -20px; left: 0px;}`

Comment them out one at a time to see if this solves the puzzle!

Comment: hello, thanks for the help,  I tried to comment out both, but it only removes other blue background images, not the one I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The image is inside the `body` tag, in your html file. Remove the `img` tag which contains this image and it should be removed.

**UPDATE**
You should remove the last three lines - the ones with `background` atribute - from this style code on your index page:

```css
<style type="text/css">
.imagePositionBox {
width:100;
height:100;
font:20pt/36pt;
background-image:url("http://satimed.com/files/resized/89767/500;500;6615ca2cc8c1c75f3a609aa30fbc514f5bb87114.png");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: 0% 25%;
}
</style>
```